# Read String and bytes from the same file java

Tags: java, io, java-io

I'm looking for a way to switch between reading bytes (as byte[]) and reading lines of Strings from a file. I know that a byte[] can be obtained form a file through a FileInputStream, and a  String can be obtained through a BufferedReader, but using both of them at the same time is proving problematic.  I know how long the section of bytes are. String encoding can be kept constant from when I write the file. The filetype is a custom one that is still in development, so I can change how I write data to it.

How can I read Strings and byte[]s from the same file in java?

Comment: Always read one type and convert when needed? You can convert String to byte[] and byte[] to String.

Comment: Why not read the entire file as a byte array and then convert the needed sections to Strings after reading the file in?

Comment: Use [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and `DataOutputStream` to keep a consistent format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read as bytes. When you have read a sequence of bytes that you know should be a string, place those bytes in an array, put the array inside a `ByteArrayInputStream` and use that as the underlying `InputStream` for a `Reader` to get the bytes as characters, then read those characters to produce a `String`.

For the later parts of this process see the related SO question on [how to create a `String` from an `InputStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string).

Answer (score 0):

Read the file as `String`s using a `BufferedReader` then use `String.getBytes()`.

Comment: When you do that, the encoding can mess up some of the original data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this:

```
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testing.txt"));
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                byte[] b = line.getBytes();
            }

        } finally {
            if(bufferedReader!=null){
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
        }
```

or

```
            FileInputStream in = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt"));
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                //read your line
            }
            in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
            int c;
            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                //read your bytes (c)
            }


        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if(bufferedReader!=null){
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read everything as bytes from the buffered input stream, and convert string sections into String's using [constructor that accepts the byte array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29):

```
 String string = new String(bytes, offset, length, "US-ASCII");
```

Depending on how the data are actually encoded, you may need to use "UTF-8" or something else as the name of the [charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).